# how to find the current version of gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

I tried

```
$ gnome-about –gnome-version
gnome-about: command not found

$ gnome-session --version
gnome-session 3.2.1
```

Why I need is because my desktop environment doesn't look like 
http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/
though wikipedia states that the default gnome version on 12.04 is 3.4.1.

Comment: found out that gnome-about nor gnome-panel no longer works in Unity/GNOME3

Comment: do i need to add ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 eventhough `gnome-shell --version` shows that i'm using 3.4.1?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Type

```
gnome-shell --version
```

in a terminal

Comment: but it doesn't look like in the gnome3 offical site

Comment: It's normal: that screenshot shows one of the multiple customization for DE (themes, wallpapers, and so on).

Comment: actually it looks awesome. i liked it. Anyway idea of which theme they are using?

Comment: Absolutely not... Each distribution using gnome3 (Fedora, Mint, Ubuntu, and so on) can count on different themes...

Comment: what would happen if i add `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` into sources?

Comment: I use that repo since 11.10 because it contains many useful addons and updates (themes, shell-extensions, and so on). I can suggest to add it and many other ones...

Comment: Such as:

ppa:upubuntu.com/themes
ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
ppa:jconti/gnome3
ppa:upubuntu.com/ext

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3477/discussion-between-jasmines-and-john)

Comment: This answer is wrong, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73212/how-to-get-the-gnome-version

Comment: FYI to anyone wondering, a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install has `GNOME Shell 42.5`.

Answer (score 4):

Your gnome version is 3.4.1 and is alright.

But you have to make sure at the time of logging in--that is, at the beginning of the session--that you select the "gnome" desktop environment among many. The other options may include:

- **GNOME Classic** *[which provides [a "GNOME Fallback" session](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gnome-3-fallback.html)]*
- **GNOME Classic** (no effects) *[which may provide an even lighter weight GNOME Fallback]*
- **Ubuntu** *[which provides Unity]*
- **Ubuntu 2D** *[which provides Unity 2D]*

When you log in (when the machine boots up, or even now by closing all applications you can log out and again log in), there is a small round symbol on the right hand side of your user name on your log in dialog box. By clicking over it you can find a drop down list of options. Select **GNOME**.

Comment: although *Fallback might be active, even if something else was chosen, as the name "Fallback" indicates.