# How find the current gnome version in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I want to know if I have gnome installed or not.
So , I have consulted this question: [how to find the current version of gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138940/how-to-find-the-current-version-of-gnome) 
and [How do I check my version of GNOME-Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13348/how-do-i-check-my-version-of-gnome-shell) . But I got different answers as mentioned in screenshot.

I am confused. So , can anyone describe me this situation?

Thank you in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the version of gnome

```
$ dpkg -l libgnome2-common
```

and for gnome-shell:

```
$ dpkg -l gnome-shell
```

works whether the packages are installed or not.

Comment: Thank you @hiro protagonist . It worked. It turned out that I have first one installed and second one not installed.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see an issue: you do NOT have gnome-shell installed so any command asking for a version of gnome-shell, or any command related to gnome-shell, will error out. And you have Unity installed and that would be the case when you installed a default Ubuntu

```
unity --version
```

will show you the version of that.

Answer (score 3):

for the version of gnome

```
$ gnome-shell --version
```